# Binding to object itself, doesn't update when individual property changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In a listbox I have a list of objects with many properties, and since I render all at once and the object it generic, I bind to the object itself.

```
<local:ItemRenderer ItemReference="{Binding Path=."}/>
```

The problem is when underlying object updates one of the properties, the `OnPropertyChanged` doesn't trigger the binding to update. Is there a way to trigger the binding to update when any of the properties change?

One idea was to have a property just for notifying, but the underlying `ObservableCollection` is type of Object, adding `BindingNotifier="{Binding Path=BindingNotifier"}` is unrecognized and would not work.

**EDIT**

This seemed like a good solution but it does not work

```
public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public MyObject Self
    {
        get { return this; }            
    }
```

then I try binding

```
<local:ItemRenderer ItemReference="{Binding Self"}/>
```

This works for initial binding, but calling

```
OnPropertyChanged("Self");
```

does not update the object.

Answer (score 2):

Reset the datacontext of the control or view or page *or all as needed* to `null` then swap it back to the instance which had recently changed. *Changing it to the same reference doesn't work...one needs both steps*.

---

Here is actual code where I needed the controls to be triggered in the same way due to a change from a command (executed from the VM to keep VM and View operation seperate) to update the Views controls during a similar situation.

The same situation occurred in the code below where individual properties to notify a change didn't update the whole instance binding as found on `CurrentBatch`. Other controls had to be updated to signify that something about `CurrentBatch` changed....

```
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = VM = new CertifyingVM();

    VM.CommandRefreshBindings = new OperationCommand(o =>
    {
        MainAccessionHeader.DataContext =
        MainHeader.DataContext = null;

        MainAccessionHeader.DataContext =
        MainHeader.DataContext = VM;

        var currentBatch = VM.CurrentBatch;
        MainAccessionHeader.CurrentBatch = null;
        MainAccessionHeader.CurrentBatch = currentBatch;

    });

    VM.LockBatchGui = new OperationCommand(o =>
    { ... }
```

---

`OperationCommand` is my `ICommand` operation which is demonstrated on my blog post entitled [Xaml: MVVM Example for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017).

How you trigger it is up to you, just remove the value of the datacontext to null then set it back.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `IMultiValueConverter` implementation and bind to both the object itself and a property that changes whenever any property of the object changes:

```
public class TheConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[0]; //return the actual object
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<local:ItemRenderer>
    <local:ItemRendered.ItemsReference>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <local:TheConverter />
            </MultiBinding.Converter>
            <Binding Path="." />
            <Binding Path="BindingNotifier" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </local:ItemRendered.ItemsReference>
</local:ItemRenderer>
```

This requires you to set the `BindingNotifier` property whenever any property of the objects is modified. The other option is to add a `<Binding>` element for each property.

Comment: This is a very useful answer. I will have to play with this and my answer to figure a hybrid operation for this scenario.